# Does Windows.CopyFile create a temporary local file while source and destination are network shares?

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-7

I have a D2007 application that uses Windows.CopyFile to copy MS Word and PowerPoint files from one network folder to another network folder. Our organization is migrating to Windows 7 from Vista. One of my migrated users got an error message that displayed a partial local folder (C:\Users\(username)\...\A100203.doc) during the copy. Does the CopyFile function cache a local copy of the document when it is copying from one network folder to another network folder or is it a direct write? I have never seen this error before and the application has been running for years on Win95, Win 98, Win2000, WinXP and Vista.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows.CopyFile does NOT cache the file on your hard drive... instead, it instructs Windows to handle the copying of the file itself (rather than you managing the streams in your own program). The output file buffer (destination) is opened, and the input buffer simply read and written. Essentially this means that the source file is spooled into system memory, then offloaded onto the destination... at no point is an additional cache file created (this would slow file copying down).

You need to provide more specific information about your error... such as either the text or an actual screenshot of the offending error message. This will allow people to provide more useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

The user that launches the copy will require read access to the original and write access to the target, regardless of caching (if the user has read access to the file, then the file can be written to a local cache, so caching/no-caching is irrelevant).

It's basic security to disallow someone to be able to copy files/directories among machines just because the security attributes between the machines are compatible.

There's little else to say without the complete text of the error message.